# Saving generic structure to document file with Codable

Tags: swift, generics, struct

I'm trying to save / encode a generic unique struct (Tree) to a document file.  Here is the following code.  It throws this error when I try to encode the unique tree:

EigenFlow[81334:7048816] -[__SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000195aee0

```
class Document: UIDocument {
    
    var saveUniqueTree : Tree<Unique<Int>> = uniqueTree
    var objectsArray = [Any]()
    
    override func contents(forType typeName: String) throws -> Any {
        
        self.objectsArray.removeAll()
        self.objectsArray.append(saveUniqueTree)

        print("ObjectsArray After: \(objectsArray)")
        
        let graphData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: objectsArray, requiringSecureCoding: false)

        return graphData
    }
```

Here are the structs I'm trying to encode / decode with Codable:

```
struct Tree<A: Codable>: Codable {
    var value: A
    var children: [Tree<A>] = []
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case value, children
    }

    init(_ value: A, children: [Tree<A>] = []) {
        self.value = value
        self.children = children
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        value = try values.decode(A.self, forKey: .value)
        children = try values.decode([Tree<A>].self, forKey: .children)
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        try container.encode(value, forKey: .value)
        try container.encode(children, forKey: .children)
    }


class Unique<A: Codable>: Identifiable, Codable {
    var value: A
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case value
    }
    
    init(_ value: A) { self.value = value }
    
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        do {
            try container.encode(value, forKey: .value)
        }
        catch {
            fatalError("Should never happen")
        }
    }
}

struct Diagram<A: Codable & Identifiable, V: View>: View {
    let tree: Tree<A>
    let node: (A) -> V
    
    typealias Key = CollectDict<A.ID, Anchor<CGPoint>>

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            node(tree.value)
               .anchorPreference(key: Key.self, value: .center, transform: {
                   [self.tree.value.id: $0]
               })
            HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(tree.children, id: \.value.id, content: { child in
                    Diagram(tree: child, node: self.node)
                })
            }
        }.backgroundPreferenceValue(Key.self, { (centers: [A.ID: Anchor<CGPoint>]) in
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                ForEach(self.tree.children, id: \.value.id, content: {
                 child in
                    let childValue = tree.value
                    Line(
                        from: proxy[centers[self.tree.value.id]!],
                        to: proxy[centers[child.value.id]!])
                        .stroke(Color.init(grayBarColor), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 7))
                        .onAppear {

                        }
                })
            }
        })
    }
}

var uniqueTree: Tree<Unique<Int>> = binaryTree.map(Unique.init)
```

var uniqueTree: Tree<Unique> = binaryTree.map(Unique.init) is saved globally and can be accessed anywhere.  I'm trying to save/encode uniqueTree into a UIDocument without throwing an above error.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: `NSKeyedArchiver` requires that the types you pass in conform to [`NSCoding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscoding), not `Codable` — unless you specifically call the [`NSKeyedArchiver.encodeEncodable(_:forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedarchiver/2924373-encodeencodable) method on an archiver you have (which doesn't exactly apply in this case). Is there a reason you're looking to use `NSKeyedArchiver` here, as opposed to an encoder of some variety?

Comment: (Specifically, the error you're getting is caused by passing a `struct` to Objective-C and `NSKeyedArchiver` calling the `NSCoding` method [`encode(with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscoding/1413933-encode) on it, which it doesn't [and can't] implement.)